# R Shiny animated slider for map

Tags: r, dictionary, animation, shiny

I'm new to Shiny and coding. I found an example that uses a choropleth map (ichorophlet function) to show crime rates across years and US states. I'd like to replicate this map in Shiny using annual poverty rates in the US. My questions are: 1) How do get the map to load on Shiny? 2) How do I get the animation button to work? Below are the R codes I used. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("U.S. Poverty Rates"),

  # Sidebar with slider that demonstrates various years
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Create a poverty map."),    

      # Animation with custom interval (in ms) to control speed, plus looping
      sliderInput("animation", "Press Play:", 1980, 2015, 1, step=1, 
                  animate=animationOptions(interval=800, loop=TRUE))),

   # Show map summarizing the values entered
   mainPanel(
      plotOutput("map")
    )   
  )
))
```

**server.R**

```
# Load libraries
library(lattice)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr) 
library(readxl)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(rMaps) 
library(rjson)
library(rCharts)
library(shiny)

# Load data and helper files
data <- read_excel("data/hstpov21.xls", sheet = "Sheet1")
source("toJASON.R")
source("ichoropleth.R")

# Remove DC
datm <- subset(na.omit(data), 
               !(State %in% c("D.C.", "District of Columbia")))

# Discreticize poverty rates
datm2 <- transform(datm,
                   State = state.abb[match(as.character(State), state.name)],
                   fillKey = cut(Poverty, 
                                 quantile(Poverty, seq(0, 1, 1/5)), 
                                 labels = LETTERS[1:5]),
                   Year = as.numeric(substr(Year, 1, 4))
                   )

# Fill colors
fills = setNames(
        c(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(5, 'YlOrRd'), 'white'),
        c(LETTERS[1:5], 'defaultFill')
        )

# Create Payload for DataMaps
dat2 <- dlply(na.omit(datm2), "Year", function(x){
        y = toJSONArray2(x, json = F)
        names(y) = lapply(y, '[[', 'State')
        return(y)
        })

# Define server logic for slider
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    # Reactive expression to compose a data frame containing all of the values
      sliderValues <- reactive({

       # Compose data frame
         data.frame(
         Name = c("Animation"),
         Value = as.character(c(input$animation)), 
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
     })  

    # Show the values using a chorophlet map
      output$map <- renderPlot({
         sliderValues()

         ichoropleth(Poverty ~ State,
         data = datm2[,1:3],
         pal = 'PuRd',
         ncuts = 5,
         animate = 'Year',
         play = TRUE)

        }) 
 })
```